# Plot Lines instead of points in scatterplot

Tags: r, regression, curve-fitting, smoothing, spline

I want to replace the points in my graph with a line like in the first picture, the second picture is what I have.

```
but its not quite what im looking for, I want a smooth line without the points

I think I have to use predict for the 1/x curve but I am not sure how,
```

Comment: Please try to make this question more reproducible by adding or generating sample data. C.f., https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info

Comment: A specific request to add to the good comment of @r2evans. Please type `dput(AM_leafP)` and `dput(AM_cost_resorb)` and paste the results into your question.

Comment: I apologize @G5W and r2evans, I pasted the dput into my questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming f(1/x) fits the data well. One can use the `lm()` function to fix the desired function y= a/x + b and then use the `predict()` function to estimate the desired points.
If a more complicated nonlinear function is required to fit the data then the `nls()` maybe required

```
x<- c(176.01685819061, 21.6704613594849, 19.007554742708, 50.1865574864131, 17.6174002411188, 40.2758022496774, 11.0963214407251, 1249.94375253114, 694.894678288085, 339.786950220117, 42.1452961176151, 220.352895161601, 19.6303352674776, 9.10350287678884, 10.6222946396451, 44.1984352318898, 21.8069112975004, 42.1237630342764, 22.7551891190248, 12.9587850506626, 12.0207189111152, 20.2704921282476, 13.3441156357956, 9.13092569988769, 1781.08346869568, 71.2690023512206, 80.2376892286713, 344.114362037227, 208.830841645638, 91.1778810401913, 2220.0120768657, 41.4820962277111, 16.5730025748281, 32.30173229022, 108.703930214512, 51.6770035143256, 709.071405759588, 87.9618878732223, 10.4198968123037, 34.4951840238729, 57.8603720445067, 72.3289197551429, 30.2366643066749, 23.8696161364716, 270.014690419247, 13.8170113452005, 39.5159584479013, 27.764841260433, 18.0311836472615, 40.5709477295999, 33.1888820958952, 9.03112843931787, 4.63738971549635, 12.7591169313099, 4.7998894219979, 8.93458248803248, 7.33904760386628, 12.0940344070925, 7.17364602165948, 6.514191844409, 9.69911157978057, 6.57874454980745, 7.90556524435596)
y<- c(0.02840637, 0.230728821, 0.2630533, 0.099628272, 0.28381032, 0.12414402, 0.45059978, 0.00400018, 0.00719533500000001, 0.014715103086687, 0.118637201789886, 0.022690875, 0.254707825, 0.54923913, 0.470708088, 0.113126176837872, 0.22928510745, 0.118697847481752, 0.219730100850697, 0.38583864, 0.4159485, 0.24666396693114, 0.374696992776912, 0.547589605297248, 0.00280728, 0.070156727820596, 0.062314855376136, 0.01453005323695, 0.02394282358199, 0.0548378613646, 0.00225224, 0.120533928, 0.301695482, 0.15479046, 0.045996497, 0.096754836, 0.00705147600000001, 0.0568428, 0.47985120103071, 0.14494777, 0.08641493, 0.069128642, 0.165362156, 0.20947132, 0.018517511, 0.36187275779699, 0.126531158458224, 0.180083867690804, 0.277297380904852, 0.1232408972382, 0.15065285976048, 0.55364067, 1.07819275643191, 0.39187665, 1.04169066418176, 0.55962324, 0.68128731, 0.41342697, 0.69699564, 0.76755492, 0.515511133042674, 0.760023430328564, 0.632465844687028)


#data frame for prediction
df <- data.frame(x=sort(x))

# fit model y= a/x + b
model <-lm( y ~ I(1/x))
#summary(model)

#plot model
plot(df$x, predict(model, df), type="l", col="blue")
#optional
points(x, y)
```

[image]

*Update - response to comments*

1. x is sorted in the data frame, so that points are plotted in order.  If not the line could go from x=1 to x=100, back to x=10 etc. thus making a mess. Try removing the sort and see what happens.
2. The `I(1/x)` term is to signal `lm` to perform the inverse transform on x first and then perform the least squares regression.
3. The `predict()` function is on the axis since that is the variable used in the plot function.  To change this just assign the output from the predict function to a better variable name and plot that. Or use the "ylab= " option.

Comment: Thanks, a couple of questions,
1) why did you sort the x values?
2) could you elaborate a bit more on this line of code model <-lm( y ~ I(1/x))?
3)why is your predict() function on the y axis

Comment: @noname See updates above

Answer (score 0):

For smoothing, you can fit a linear model as foolws:

```
m <- lm(AM_cost_resorb~I(1/AM_leafP), data=data)
```

Then extract the predictied values on a new data set that covers the range of the exposure variable.

```
newx <- seq(min(data$AM_leafP), max(data$AM_leafP), by=0.01)
pr <- predict(m, newdata=data.frame(AM_leafP=newx))
```

And visualize:

```
plot(AM_cost_resorb~AM_leafP, data=data, type="p", pch= 15, col="red",ylab="Cost of reabsorbtion (kg C m^-2 yr^-1)", xlab="leaf P before senescence (g P/m2)", ylim=c(0,500), las=1)
lines(newx, y=pr, col="blue", lwd=2)
```

[image]

---

Data:

```
data <- structure(list(AM_cost_resorb = c(176.01685819061, 21.6704613594849, 
19.007554742708, 50.1865574864131, 17.6174002411188, 40.2758022496774, 
11.0963214407251, 1249.94375253114, 694.894678288085, 339.786950220117, 
42.1452961176151, 220.352895161601, 19.6303352674776, 9.10350287678884, 
10.6222946396451, 44.1984352318898, 21.8069112975004, 42.1237630342764, 
22.7551891190248, 12.9587850506626, 12.0207189111152, 20.2704921282476, 
13.3441156357956, 9.13092569988769, 1781.08346869568, 71.2690023512206, 
80.2376892286713, 344.114362037227, 208.830841645638, 91.1778810401913, 
2220.0120768657, 41.4820962277111, 16.5730025748281, 32.30173229022, 
108.703930214512, 51.6770035143256, 709.071405759588, 87.9618878732223, 
10.4198968123037, 34.4951840238729, 57.8603720445067, 72.3289197551429, 
30.2366643066749, 23.8696161364716, 270.014690419247, 13.8170113452005, 
39.5159584479013, 27.764841260433, 18.0311836472615, 40.5709477295999, 
33.1888820958952, 9.03112843931787, 4.63738971549635, 12.7591169313099, 
4.7998894219979, 8.93458248803248, 7.33904760386628, 12.0940344070925, 
7.17364602165948, 6.514191844409, 9.69911157978057, 6.57874454980745, 
7.90556524435596), AM_leafP = c(0.02840637, 0.230728821, 0.2630533, 
0.099628272, 0.28381032, 0.12414402, 0.45059978, 0.00400018, 
0.00719533500000001, 0.014715103086687, 0.118637201789886, 0.022690875, 
0.254707825, 0.54923913, 0.470708088, 0.113126176837872, 0.22928510745, 
0.118697847481752, 0.219730100850697, 0.38583864, 0.4159485, 
0.24666396693114, 0.374696992776912, 0.547589605297248, 0.00280728, 
0.070156727820596, 0.062314855376136, 0.01453005323695, 0.02394282358199, 
0.0548378613646, 0.00225224, 0.120533928, 0.301695482, 0.15479046, 
0.045996497, 0.096754836, 0.00705147600000001, 0.0568428, 0.47985120103071, 
0.14494777, 0.08641493, 0.069128642, 0.165362156, 0.20947132, 
0.018517511, 0.36187275779699, 0.126531158458224, 0.180083867690804, 
0.277297380904852, 0.1232408972382, 0.15065285976048, 0.55364067, 
1.07819275643191, 0.39187665, 1.04169066418176, 0.55962324, 0.68128731, 
0.41342697, 0.69699564, 0.76755492, 0.515511133042674, 0.760023430328564, 
0.632465844687028)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-63L))
```

Comment: How do I remove the points such that only the line remains?

Comment: Replace `type="p"` with `type="n"` in the `plot` command.

Comment: I was hoping to get a smooth spline line for the curve like in the first picture with the lines, as I was already able to get similar line to yours with this code
```   lines((AM_leafP*1000)[order(AM_leafP*1000)], (AM_cost_resorb[,1])[order(AM_leafP*1000)], pch=16, col="blue")
```